# Can you heat Bismuth crystals to reset the oxide layer for new colors?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, metal, crystal-structure

I'd like to get a bismuth crystal with small structures and deep blue colors for a ring I want to make. I can find these properties in different crystals online but never together. Can I just take a crystal with the right shape and blowtorch it to create a new oxide layer? Would I first have to chemically remove the thin oxide layer?

Comment: I have made Bismuth crystals where I etched the oxide layer off and tried heat treatment to reproduce the colored oxide layer. It did not work in a $200^\circ C$ furnace, but that doesn't mean a torch couldn't, I would suspect that it is non-trival though.

Comment: Just a thought, but perhaps a thin oxide could be deposited by making bismuth the anode in a dilute sodium or potassium hydroxide bath.

Comment: Would that bath "redo" the oxide layer though? And wouldn't that create a thicker, more even layer than one resulting from the uneven cooling of a crystal? Also, do you know if nail polish would work to preserve the layer without dissolving it?

Comment: thickness is a function of time and current Nail polish remover will not dissolve the oxide.